# why is semicolon considered as a separator for query string in werkzeug 2.3.x

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a production application running flask==2.2.5 and werkzeug==2.2.3, need to upgrade the werkzeug package to version 2.3.8 or 3.0.1. But when I tested after updating, there is some change in the werkzeug package that is not mentioned in the change log which basically considers the ";" character along with "&" in the query string as a seprator and separates it out."&" was the only separator in the older versions. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix this?

Example:

For a sample request url - http://example.com/path?param1=p1value1&param2=p2value1;p2value2

The expected output for request.params should be
`ImmutableMultiDict([('param1', 'p1value1'), ('param2', 'p2value1;p2value2')])`

But the output that I am getting is
`ImmutableMultiDict([('param1', 'p1value1'), ('param2', 'p2value1', 'p2value2', '')])`

Comment: It's odd that you encountered that when *up*grading.  Equivalency of `;` with `&` as a query parameter separator is an obsolete feature, not a new one.  Maybe werkzeug added a compatibility option that enables the old semantics, or changed the default setting of an existing one.

Comment: It looks like at version 2.3.0, [Werkzeug switched from its bespoke internal URL parsing code to standard `urllib.parse`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-2-3-0).  That's the right timing, and it seems a reasonable explanation for the observed difference in behavior.

Comment: And `urllib.parse`'s query-string functions used to support both `&` and `;` as query-parameter separators, but they don't any longer.  (They accept only one separator character, which defaults to `&`.)  Are you running on Python older than 3.6.13?  If so, then upgrading your Python to at least that version may resolve the issue for you.  Or to the latest release of whatever more recent Python 3 version you are using.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I did read about the Werkzeug reference you have shared. Looks like the `urllib.parse` implementation is the problem we have now. We are using python 3.8 version but still facing the issue

Comment: In Python 3.6 - 3.9, the change to query string parsing was applied separately in each version's revision history.  For Python 3.8 you want at least v3.8.8.  (Assuming that the behavior of `urllib.parse` is indeed the explanation for you issue.)

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger. As you had mentioned, v3.8.8 and above doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @John Bollinger mentioned,

Werkzeug v2.3.0 switched from its bespoke internal URL parsing code to standard urllib.parse. urllib.parse's query-string functions used to support both & and ; as query-parameter separators, but they don't any longer. They accept only one separator character, which defaults to &. Python 3.6 - 3.9, the change to query string parsing was applied separately in each version's revision history. For Python 3.8 you want at least v3.8.8.